# How to read in a command line as floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I read in a command line as floats or ints?

```
test.py 11 22.4 11.7 99.9 69
```

I've tried:

```
numbersList = float(sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)])
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import sys
args = map(float, sys.argv[1:])
```

Or if you prefer a list comprehension:

```
args = [float(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
```

Comment: Note that `map` returns a map object in py3.x.

Answer (score 4):

A higher-level solution, using `argparse` instead of `sys.argv` directly:

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('values', nargs="*", type=float)
args = p.parse_args()

numbersList = args.values
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate on your list, try:

```
numbersList = [float(sys.argv[i]) for i in range(1, len(sys.argv))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only important that you read in the information as numbers and don't need to differentiate between ints and floats you could try something like this

```
import sys

print sum(map(float, sys.argv[1:]))
```